# how to insert only one word from a string into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I post only one word into the database.

I only need to insert one word from the values entered by a user.

For example: `this is my car` to insert only the word `this`

Here is my present code:

```
$write=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `staff_description` (`id`, `staff_name`, `description`, `description2`,`writer`, `date_stamp`) VALUES ('$id', '$staff_name', '$description', '$description2', '$user', '$date_stamp');") or die(mysql_error());
```

please assist

Comment: dont use mysq_* use mysqli_*...

Comment: One word? What do you mean?

Comment: whats the problem? do you have any message error?

Comment: @MichaelBuluma If you ever ask another question, please be more specific as to what your goal is. I edited your question to reflect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to take only 1 word from user inputs and insert it into your database you could use `explode()` function as follows:

```
$description1 = $_POST['description1'];
$arr = explode(' ',$description1 ); // this will explode the string after every space

echo $arr[0]; //this is the first word
echo $arr[1];
echo $arr[2];
```

you could use this to insert into database like :

```
insert into database VALUES($arr[0])
// this will take the first word from the user input
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table has only 1 column then you can simply use the `INSERT` query. If your table has multiple rows there can be 2 cases:

1. The row already exits - In this case you will have to use the `UPDATE` query.
2. The row doesn't exist - You may insert "1 word" into any column using the `INSERT` query. The other columsn will take default values which you have defined while creating the table OR you can simple add blanks if you plan to use those columns later.

Comment: how do i do that? i just need to drop all the other submitted data and insert one word

Comment: We need more details. Which language are you using? How does your form look like? If you are using PHP, this tutorial will help you.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp